# "The mysqli extension is missing" but it is located in the extension directory

Tags: php, iis, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am setting up PHPMyAdmin to run on IIS 8. I have followed the steps in this tutorial: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php

However, PHP is complaining:

> The mysqli extension is missing.

So I confirmed that php_mysqli.dll is uncommented and that the dll is located in the correct file location:

extension=php_mysqli.dll

extension_dir = "C:\php\ext"

I rebooted the website after ensuring this was the case and I continue getting the error.

EDIT:
Adding

```
<?php 
phpinfo(); 
exit;
```

gives me this for mysqli config:

> mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $

as the client api library version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should check if you restart your IIS server or not after changing php.ini file.

If it doesn't help, you can check PHP settings for the IIS, open index.php file and put this code in the beginning:

```
<?php

phpinfo();
exit;
```

After that, refresh your website. You'll see all PHP settings for IIS. Here you can find the path to php.ini file and check is that your file you were changed.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am rebooting the server every time I change php.ini, i will update though with anything phpinfo() spits back.

Comment: Okay a little fiddling fixed my problem.  I am seeing this version of the mysqli dll:  mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: bf9ad53b11c9a57efdb1057292d73b928b8c5c77 $

Comment: A little more fiddling indicates that my original request was answered.  Thank you.  PHPMyAdmin still does not work but that is a different issue :)